# If property values of objects are equal in two array of objects then merge those objects into single object

Tags: javascript

If x property value matches in both the objects in 2 arrays. merge those objects into single object.

```
var data3= [{"x":"Mfg1","y":83840.901245},{"x":"Mfg2","y":74804.973325},{"x":"Mfg3","y":81869.98221666666},{"x":"Mfg4","y":36503.152352499994}];
var data4 = [{"x":"Mfg1","y":83840.901245},{"x":"Mfg2","y":74804.973325},{"x":"Mfg8","y":51869.98221666666},{"x":"Mfg4","y":36503.152352499994}];
```

output array should be:

```
[{"x":"Mfg1","y":83840.901245},{"x":"Mfg2","y":74804.973325},{"x":"Mfg3","y":81869.98221666666},{"x":"Mfg4","y":36503.152352499994},{"x":"Mfg8","y":51869.98221666666}]
```

Comment: Nice! So, what have you already tried?

Comment: Plus a proper formatting could help us better understand your code ;)

Comment: _.unionBy(obj1, obj2, key) ..I think it works

Comment: Feels like Lodash.. But please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: now check the question dude. I rephrased it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the stringified version of theobject to check for duplicates:

```
const unique = (getKey, s = new Set) => el => !s.has(getKey(el)) && s.add(getKey(el));

const result = data3.concat(data4).filter( unique(el => JSON.stringify(el)) );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..jonas